# Any way to hide arrow on dropdown lists in mobile IE (Windows Phone 7.5)?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, drop-down-menu

I'm using a custom background on a  element but the default arrow still shows up.  Mobile IE doesn't support either the 'appearance' or '-ms-appearance' css properties so I'm kind of at a loss about what to do.  It sticks out like the proverbial sore thumb.

Answer (score 9):

As you said [IE <= 10 doesn't support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh781508.aspx#user_interface) the `appearance` property.

The only thing I could find is a [blog post by Charles Morris](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx#step5) where he shows a solution for IE 10:

**CSS**

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  ...
</select>
```

Unfortunately I have no Windows Phone 7.5 device to test if this works, but I created a [reduced testcase](http://jsfiddle.net/TimPietrusky/v759w/) for you to try it out!

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for the solution for Internet Explorer 10 and this did what I wanted (as a replacement for -webkit-appearance: none )

Comment: Thank you! This works fine on Windows Phone 8, but Windows Phone 7.5 ignores it.